# Convert numerical data in csv from bytes to kilobytes using Python

Tags: python, csv

What I have at the moment is that I take in a cvs file and determine the related data between a given start time and end time. I write this relevant data into a different cvs file. All of this works correctly.

What I want to do is convert all the numerical data (not touching the date or time) from the original cvs file from bytes into kilobytes and only take one decimal place when presenting the kilobyte value. These altered numerical data is what I want written into the new cvs file.

The numerical data seems to be read as a string so they  I’m a little unsure how to do this, any help would be appreciated.

The original CSV (when opened in excel) is presented like this:

```
Date:-------- | Title1:----- | Title2: | Title3: | Title4:

01/01/2016 | 32517293 | 45673 | 0.453 |263749

01/01/2016 | 32721993 | 65673 | 0.563 |162919

01/01/2016 | 33617293 | 25673 | 0.853 |463723
```

But I want the new CSV to look something like this:

```
Date:-------- | Title1:--- | Title2: | Title3: | Title4:

01/01/2016 | 32517.2 | 45673 | 0.0 | 263.749

01/01/2016 | 32721.9 | 65673 | 0.0 | 162.919

01/01/2016 | 33617.2 | 25673 | 0.0 | 463.723
```

My Python function so far:

```
def edit_csv_file(Name,Start,End):

#Open file to be written to 
f_writ = open(logs_folder+csv_file_name, 'a')
#Open file to read from (i.e. the raw csv data from the windows machine)
csvReader = csv.reader(open(logs_folder+edited_csv_file_name,'rb'))

#Remove double quotation marks when writing new file
writer = csv.writer(f_writ,lineterminator='\n', quotechar = '"')


for row in csvReader:

    #Write the data relating to the modules greater than 10 seconds
    if get_sec(row[0][11:19]) >= get_sec(Start):
        if get_sec(row[0][11:19]) <= get_sec(End):
            writer.writerow(row)

f_writ.close()
```

Comment: Do you define a kB as 1000 bytes or as 1024 bytes? What have you done so far? Please provide the code you have so for and tell where you're stuck currently. Are you allowed to use additional modules like `pandas`?

Comment: I think you made mistake while convert from byte to kb; 32517293 byte is 31755.16895 kb not 32517.2

Comment: Yes I realised my mistake, I want to take 1kB as 1024 bytes, apologies for the confusion

Comment: @frank-zalkow answer will work then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should do what you need:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv', 'rb') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(next(csv_input))    # write header

    for cols in csv_input:
        for col in range(1, len(cols)):
            try:
                cols[col] = "{:.1f}".format(float(cols[col]) / 1024.0)
            except ValueError:
                pass
        csv_output.writerow(cols)
```

Giving you the following output csv file:

```
Date:--------,Title1:-----,Title2:,Title3:,Title4:
01/01/2016,31755.2,44.6,0.0,257.6
01/01/2016,31955.1,64.1,0.0,159.1
01/01/2016,32829.4,25.1,0.0,452.9
```

Tested using Python 2.7.9

Comment: When I use your code I get     "ValueError: could not convert string to float:" for edited_row = "{:.1f}".format(float(row[i]) / 1024.0)

Comment: I am guessing the data you are testing with is a bit different to what you have shown. I suggest you add `print row` just before that line. Are you using Python 2.x or 3.x ?

Comment: I am using 2.7.10 and also when I check "print row[i]" It prints as a number like 48.098821578871316

Comment: Also when I use int instead of float it gives an error "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '48.098821578871316' "

Comment: `print row` should have given you the whole row as a list. Each entry should be quoted as string. It is a bit difficult to say what is wrong as the code you seem to be running is different from the solution I posted.

Comment: I am cycling through all the elements in each the row using row_element_count = sum(1 for element in row )                                               for i in range(1,row_element_count):
 for i in range(1,row_element_count):
 print row[i]
 edit_row = "{:.1f}".format(float(row[i])/1024.0)
 writer.writerow(edit_row)

Comment: I see that none of my formatting was saved in my above comment. I think I have found the issue to be that some entries in a row are empty i.e = “ “ so it can’t convert them to strings. I can’t remove them as if they are empty they need to remain empty or equal zero

Comment: Note `row_element_count = len(row)`

Comment: You need to add exception handling to cater for empty columns. I have updated the solution to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

int() is the standard way in python to convert a string to an int. it is used like

```
int("5") + 1
```

this will return 6. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

if `s` is your string representing a byte value, you can convert to a string representing a kilobyte value with a single decimal place like this:

```
'%.1f' % (float(s)/1024)
```

Alternatively:

```
str(round(float(s)/1024, 1))
```

**EDIT:**

To prevent errors for non-digit strings, you can just make a conditional

```
'%.1f' % (float(s)/1024) if s.isdigit() else ''
```

Comment: It works for nearly all entries on each row however sometimes an entry = " " which throws an error "ValueError: could not convert string to float:". Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: you could use `try-except`-blocks to catch the `ValueError` and keep the entry untouched

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what else you may find yourself working on, I'd be tempted to use pandas for this one - given a file with the contents you describe, after importing the pandas module:

```
import pandas as pd
```

Read in the csv file (automagically recognising that the 1st line is a header) - the delimiter in your case may not need specifying - if it's the default comma - but other delimiters are available - I'm a fan of the pipe '|' character.

```
csv = pd.read_csv("pandas_csv.csv",delimiter="|")
```

Then you can enrich/process your data as you like using the column names as references.

For example, to convert a column by some factor you might write:

```
csv['Title3'] = csv['Title3']/1024
```

The datatypes are again, automatically determined, so if a column is all numeric (as in the example) there's no need to do any conversion from datatype to datatype, 99% of the time, it figures it out correctly based on the data in the file.

Once you're happy with the edits, type

```
csv
```

To see a representation of the results, and then

```
csv.to_csv("pandas_csv.csv")
```

To save the results (in this case, overwriting the original file, but you may want to write something more like:

```
csv.to_csv("pandas_csv_kilobytes.csv")
```

There are more useful/powerful functions available, but I know no easier method for manipulating tabular data than this - it's better and more reliable than Excel, and in years to come, you will celebrate the day you started using pandas!

In this case, you've opened, edited and saved the file using the following 4 lines of code:

```
import pandas as pd
csv = pd.read_csv("pandas_csv.csv",delimiter="|")
csv['Title3'] = csv['Title3']/1024
csv.to_csv("pandas_csv_kilobytes.csv")
```

That's about as powerful and convenient as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

And another solution using a func (bytesto) from: gist.github.com/shawnbutts/3906915

```
def bytesto(bytes, to):
    a = {'k' : 1, 'm': 2, 'g' : 3, 't' : 4, 'p' : 5, 'e' : 6 }
    r = float(bytes)
    for i in range(a[to]):
        r = r / 1024
    return(int(r)) # ori not return int

with open('csvfile.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='|', quotechar='|')
    row=iter(data)
    next(row) # Jump title
    for row in data:
        print 'kb= ' + str(bytesto((row[1]), 'k')), 'kb= ' + str(bytesto((row[2]), 'k')), 'kb= ' + str(bytesto((row[3]), 'k')), 'kb= ' + str(bytesto((row[4]), 'k'))
```

Result:

```
kb= 31755 kb= 44 kb= 0 kb= 257
kb= 31955 kb= 64 kb= 0 kb= 159
kb= 32829 kb= 25 kb= 0 kb= 452
```

Hope this help u a bit.